# Facebook API/Graph 2.5 (events) not supported anymore, how to upgrade?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using this query to get all events from a location:

https://graph.facebook.com/116403805045358/events?fields=name,description,place&limit=100&access_token=...

This returns no more results, only a blank data JSON field.

Logged into my Facebook developer account and there was a warning "Graph 2.5 not supported anymore since 12th of april 2018". Changed site/roles to v2.12 but it still doesn't return anything.

Any ideas how to change the query above to work again?

Comment: Read https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes

Comment: @WizKid: I've read this but this doesn't solve my problem. Is it possible that i need an "page access token" for that page to get the event infos like name/place/description?

Comment: So you've read it but not understood it ... This is "grubby little hands off" for everyone right now. The review process is being reworked to find a compromise between privacy and genuine app requirements, but until that is done, all things are on hold. You don't need any different kind of token right now, you need _patience._

Comment: I'm definitely having the same issue as is a lot of my users on their pages as well.  I think this started when 3.0 came out but not sure.  I resubmitted my app for the required review process again to see if it magically starts working after approved.  Of course it might not get approved since my app technically doesn't "work" without this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

At this precise moment Facebook is returning events for some pages and for other pages its not returning any events. You can easily test using https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer.

For the page you mention Facebook is not returning events at the moment as you can test here:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=hirschnbg%2Fevents&version=v2.12

Comment: Is there any official information on this? It's very confusing since some pages are returning events, some not, but it isn't even the same for different access tokens?

Comment: today i noticed that the pages that return events are just returning 19 events & showing past events first & no paging. this is happening using both users or apps access token  It seems  that the exception is when a user was invited, is attending or interested in the event. In this case, with user access token, you can get event data using the user events endpoint (/me/events) or querying the event endpoint. i didn’t test with page access tokens.

i’ve also noticed that the fields: owner, updated_time & is_canceled where removed. If you query any of those you may get permissions error.